# Is the word "student" an indefinite pronoun?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

Is the word "student" an indefinite pronoun? 
I am just confused about this word.
Would you like to express your views regarding this?

Comment: No, it is a common noun.

Comment: But indefinite pronouns can also be males or females. The word "student"can be either male or female, so sir why can't we call it the indefinite pronoun?

Comment: Maybe because it's more specific, that is, you can't just call any person a student.

Comment: Yes ,but this sentence is confusing me. a student can be a person. It can be a male or female.  Indefinite pronouns can be also males or females, that is why I asked this question, sir.

Comment: You wrote "I am just confused about this word". Did you mean "student" or "indefinite pronoun" when you wrote "this word"?

Comment: Indefinite pronouns are things like *anybody*, *nobody*, or *everyone*.  "Student" isn't like that.  It's just a noun.  You could say "every student" or "any student", but that doesn't make it a pronoun.

Comment: To be an indefinite pronoun, it must first be a pronoun. Being able to be used for both males and females is ***not*** an indication of pronoun-ness.

Answer (score 4):

From Google:

> Indefinite pronouns are words which replace nouns without specifying which noun they replace.
>
> Singular: another, anybody, anyone, anything, each, either, everybody, everyone, everything, little, much, neither, nobody, no one, nothing, one, other, somebody, someone, something.
>
> Plural: both, few, many, others, several.

A noun can be used in an indefinite sense to mean "anyone who is" - e.g:

> Give it to a student.

Means *give it to anyone who is a student.*  But *student* is a noun, not a pronoun.  Only the words above are indefinite pronouns.

Answer (score 3):

"student" is a normal noun, you can say "a student" and form the plural "students". You can't do this with any pronoun. And a lot of nouns have only one form for both sexes: teacher, doctor, artist etc.

The list of pronouns is limited.
http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/pronouns1.htm

A pronoun replaces a noun: Peter is my brother. You can replace "Peter" by "he". What noun should "student" replace?

Comment: I've seen people pluralize "someone"/"somebody"; in particular, "several someones" is a reasonable enough thing to say. Most pronouns don't seem to exhibit this, though.